# Can access an object via console during debugging, but code throws an error

Tags: javascript, angularjs-scope, google-chrome-devtools, v8

This problem is honestly the strangest thing I have encountered. I have no idea whether or not it's able to be reproduced, so I'm just asking for some input on possible causes.

[image: step.transit can be accessed via console, but throws errors on the code side]

The code is accessing a property (transit) on an object inside a lodash 'each' loop. The object is called step.

The code throws an exception when it tries to access a property on transit, on step (step.transit.propName). It says 'transit' is undefined.

But when you type 'step.transit' into the console, somehow the debugging tools are able to access it!

The code, and the V8 inspector tools, somehow aren't looking at the same thing. What on earth is happening here?

You'll have to look at the screenshot there to really grasp what's going on. Notice how the watch expressions show step['transit'] being both available, and unavailable at the same time....

It's strange, when I stop the code at that line, and type 'step.transit' into the console, I get the appropriate object. But there's some crazy thing in the code, where it can't seem to execute it.

This is an AngularJS app. Is there any way I could have screwed this data up in order to cause this weird error?

Comment: The watchpoint that shows `undefined` has mispelled `transit` as `tranist`.

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much... I was looking for a spelling error, guess I didn't try hard enough there....